# Python-Oracle Passing in a Cursor Out Parameter

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, database-cursor

I am trying to call a stored procedure between python and an oracle db. The problem I am having is passing a cursor out-parameter.

The Oracle stored procedure is essentially:

```
create or replace procedure sp_procedure(
    cid int, 
    rep_date date,
    ret out sys_refcursor
) is
begin

  open ret for 
  select  
 ...
  end;
```

The python code calling to the database is:

```
import cx_Oracle
from datetime import date

connstr='user/pass@127.0.0.1:2521/XE'
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)
curs = conn.cursor()

cid = 1
rep_date = date(2011,06,30)

curs.callproc('sp_procedure', (cid, rep_date, curs))
```

The error is:

```
curs.callproc('sp_procedure', (cid, rep_date, curs))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

I've also tried passing a dictionary as the keywordsParameters:

```
cid = 1
rep_date = date(2011,06,30)

call_params = {'cid': cid, 'rep_date': rep_date, 'ret': curs}
curs.callproc('sp_procedure', (cid, rep_date, curs), call_params)
```

Returns the same error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

After a couple of hours of googling and trail/error, here's the solution:

```
cid = 1
rep_date = date(2011,06,30)

l_cur = curs.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)
l_query = curs.callproc('sp_procedure', (cid,rep_date,l_cur))

l_results = l_query[2]

for row in l_results:
    print row

# Column Specs
for row in l_results.description:
    print row
```

Comment: remember all cap CURSOR

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curs = con.cursor() 
out_curs = con.cursor() 

curs.execute("""
BEGIN 
    sp_procedure(:cid, :rep_date, :cur); 
END;""", cid=cid, rep_date=rep_date, ret=outcurs)
```

Comment: Hi Scott, I managed to get the callproc() method to work. Thanks.