# Call oracle stored procedure with cursor output parameter from python script

Tags: python, oracle, stored-procedures, cursor, cx-oracle

I am trying to call a oracle stored procedure with 2 in and 1 out parameter from python script. The problem I am having is passing a cursor out-parameter.

The Oracle stored procedure is essentially:

```
  PROCEDURE ci_lac_state 
     (LAC_ID_IN IN  VARCHAR2,  
      CI_ID_IN  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
      CGI_ID    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  AS
  BEGIN
      OPEN cgi_id FOR
      ...
  END;
```

The python code calling to the database is:

```
  #! /usr/bin/python

  import cx_Oracle

  lac='11508'
  ci='9312'

  try:
      my_connection=cx_Oracle.Connection('login/passwd@db_name')
  except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError,info:
      print "Logon Error:",info
      sys.exit()

  my_cursor=my_connection.cursor()
  cur_var=my_cursor.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)

  my_cursor.callproc("cgi_info.ci_lac_state", [lac, ci, cur_var])

  print cur_var.getvalue()
```

And I get such cursor value as the result:

```
  <__builtin__.OracleCursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to login@db_name>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try `print cur_var.getvalue(pos=0)` ? or may be pos=2 if you need to retreive cur_var which is CGI_ID

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python-Oracle Passing in a Cursor Out Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821372/python-oracle-passing-in-a-cursor-out-parameter)

Comment: To FoxMaSk. Yes. I've tried to do this "print cur_var.getvalue(pos=0)", but I get the same result "<__builtin__.OracleCursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to login@db_name>>". The "pos=2" lead to new errors:  print cur_var.getvalue(pos=1)
IndexError: Variable_GetSingleValue: array size exceeded

Comment: To ThinkJet. Unfortunately, my problem is different to post "Python-Oracle Passing in a Cursor Out Parameter"

Answer (score 1):

I've just had similar issue. `cur_var` has type `<type 'cx_Oracle.CURSOR'>` and `cur_var.getvalue()` gets object of type `<type 'OracleCursor'>`. To get data you have to fetched them from the OracleCursor object. Try for example:

```
print cur_var.getvalue().fetchall()
```

To see more function of OracleCursor object just check its directory:

```
dir(cur_var.getvalue())
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can define your output and then loop through using an implicit cursor like this:

```
outVal = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)
```

`something = cursor.callproc(<your procedure name>, [outVal,<input variable here>])`

```
for implicitCursor in cursor.getimplicitresults():
    for row in implicitCursor:
        
        fout.write(''.join(row)) # note: tuple conversion inside ()
        fout.write('\n')
```