# Connecting to oracle database using python(cx_oracle)

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to oracle database using cx_Oracle in python. I am able to connect to the database and pull the data.

Now I am trying to connect to one more database where I have to call a security procedure first and then only I can see data in the underlying tables. Can you please help me in calling the procedure by adjusting the below block of code. My procedure will be like:  exec ef.applogin('1234')

```
def connect_oracle():
    import cx_Oracle
    import pandas as pd
    ip = 'some_ip'
    port = 1521
    SID = 'some_SID'
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect('user_name', 'password', dsn_tns)
    #Procedure to be executed here..    
    query = """ SELECT * from table_name """
    df_ora = pd.read_sql(query, con=connection)
    return df_ora

connect_oracle()
```

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call oracle stored procedure with cursor output parameter from python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095690/call-oracle-stored-procedure-with-cursor-output-parameter-from-python-script)

Comment: and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6829544/8353711)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create def for connect by Oracle. for execute procedure use cursor. Don't forget close connect and cursor. Also in case exception.

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

ip = 'some_ip'
port = 1521
SID = 'some_SID'
user_name = 'user_name'
password = 'password'
query = """ SELECT * from table_name """

def connect_oracle(ip, port, SID, user_name, password):
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user_name, password, dsn_tns)
    return connection

def get_df(conn, query):
    df_ora = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn)
    return df_ora


def execute_proc(conn, procname, param):    
    my_cursor=conn.cursor()
    my_cursor.callproc(procname, param)
    conn.commit()

def execute_func(conn, procname, param):    
    my_cursor=conn.cursor()
    out_parameter = my_cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
    qw = my_cursor.callfunc(procname, out_parameter)
    return qw

conn1 = connect_oracle(ip, port, SID, user_name, password)
df = get_df(conn1, query)
df.head()
execute_proc(conn1, "insert_temp", [])
execute_func(conn1, "get_version", [])
```

Function for test:

```
create or replace function get_version
return number
is
    v_version NUMBER(8) := 11;
begin
    return v_version;
end;
```

Procedure for test:

```
create table temp (clm number);
create or replace procedure insert_temp
is
    v_version NUMBER(8) := 11;
begin
    insert into temp(clm) values(v_version);
end;
select *  from temp
```